# Why was my "not an answer" flag rejected here?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

Below [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58074859/android-programming-using-java/58074967#58074967) the OP made an answer containing his code. It obviously should have been an edit to the question instead of an answer as it provides necessary information to the original question and does not try to answer it in any way.

Based on the above observations I have flagged it as "Not an answer" which I think is the correct decision. Others have commented advising to delete the answer and edit the code into the original post instead which reinforced my belief.

Fast forward a few hours, I'm doing reviews and trying to flag another "Not an answer" when I get the following warning:

> Your recent flag was declined - please review it before flagging this post!

I followed the link and realized that my flag on the originally mentioned answer was declined with the following message:

> declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

My question is, am I (or rather, are we) in the wrong for flagging that answer or was that an error on the moderator's side? I know flag rejections are not reversible, I ask about this case to be able to avoid similar situations in the future.

Comment: You seem to be correct. It appears that OP submitted an answer instead of editing. I guess a mod misclicked or misread the context.

Comment: I'll let the moderator know about this question.

Comment: Well, mistakes happen and I don't really mind the accidental rejection. Just wanted to make sure whether I have the right idea about the whole concept of reviewing and flagging. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: It is worth to keep in mind that a reviewer and a moderator ONLY see the answer you flagged. If it isn't clear at first sight why you flagged a post either use a custom flag or leave a comment to provide context for those that get to evaluate your flag. They won't by default visit the Q/A page to see everything in full glory.

Comment: Do know that both the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) chatrooms have regulars that can advice when you're unsure if a regular flag will fly. They are happy to help.

Comment: @rene Oh, I did not know that. Now I can understand the rejection because (without context) the code-only answer could look like a valid answer if one doesn't know that it's from the same person that originally asked the question.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, I missed that this was the OP of the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You were correct to flag the way you flagged; but if you suspect the moderator may get confused you can always use a custom flag to say:

> "The OP added their code that was supposed to be in the question into an answer instead. I've edited their question to include that code. Please delete this post."

Comment: That's a smart way to kill the cat George, but [...]. 

Comment: Will do so in future cases where the answer being a non-answer might not be obvious from the context. Thanks!